# Why are "history" and "add comment" spaced so far apart on the /election page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, election

[image]

As you can see, the "history" and "add comment" buttons are spaced very far apart; exactly the height of the `user-details` div.

I personally think it should be changed to look something like this:

[image]

This integrates the `comments-link` into the `post-menu` div.

Edit: Ah... Scrolling down the page, I now understand (sort of) why it looks like that... the spacing is for the comments if there are any.

[image]

What I still don't understand, though, is why the comments and "add comment" button are offset to the right by approximately the width of the "history" link, compared to them being aligned to the left like in regular posts:

[image]

(Yes, it's another reference to the most popular SU question to date)

Oh yeah, and another thing: I'm running Firefox 3.6.13 for Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meercat.

Answer (score 1):

*My apologies for original response*

That being said, It appears to be the difference of the parent table that used to hold the vote column. With that being absent (but presumably brought back during the second stage) things should align. But for now, the mismatch amount looks to be a `<td class="votecell">` off.

Original posts:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="votecell>
      <!-- Upp/Down Vote -->
    </td>
    <td class="postcell">
      <div>
        <!-- Post DIV -->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="votecell">
      <!-- spacer -->
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- comments DIV -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

turns in to

```
<!-- Post DIV -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="votecell">
      <!-- spacer -->
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- comments DIV -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Interesting that they extract the post in to a `<div id="post-####" ...>` and open a table for the comments section just to emulate the votecell indent, but didn't do so for the nomination itself.

Comment: Even with the comments, I'm wondering why they're offset to the right by so much unlike in regular posts like this one.

Comment: Touché: Appears to be because the nominations now have a parent div not a table. Formatting was altered but no accommodations made. My apologies to OP. _(Further inspection looks like modifications were made due to absent reputation table cell)_