# Comments on election nominations are out-dented, not indented

Tags: bug, design, election-page

In a site election page, there are nominations, and there can be comments on the nominations. The comments on these nominations are "outdented" instead of indented.

In searching meta.se for a duplicate (which I could not find), I found this other post about comments on nominations: [Why are “history” and “add comment” spaced so far apart on the /election page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75381/why-are-history-and-add-comment-spaced-so-far-apart-on-the-election-page)

What's nice about that post is that the asker included some screen-shots, I want to reproduce that screenshot here, and it is what the page looked like back in 2011:

[image: Back in 2011]

Now, [the page looks like](https://superuser.com/election/1#post-234921):

[image: Current]

Notice how the comments are "outdented" relative to the nomination post. This makes the comments "prouder", and makes it hard to scroll though a nomination page and identify the difference between them. It is also different to all the normal site posts, where you have answers, and then "indented" comments.

Please restore the "indent" nature of comments on election nominations.